# EXISTING equivalent to HAVING

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssms

This works:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentDay] AS
        AGGREGATE( 
            [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember,
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
    MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentMonth] AS
        AGGREGATE( 
            [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.parent,
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
SELECT
    NON EMPTY 
    { [Measures].[CurrentDay],
        [Measures].[CurrentMonth] } 
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
    { [Date].[Calendar].[Date] }
    HAVING [Measures].[CurrentDay]<>null //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<having line
    ON ROWS
From [Adventure Works]
```

Returning the following from the version of Adventure Works that I have:

[image]

If I comment out the line `HAVING [Measures].[CurrentDay]<>null` then this happens:

[image]

Is there another way of eliminating the rows that are `null` for `CurrentDay` without using `HAVING` ?

I've tried using `EXISTING` without any success:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentDay] AS
        AGGREGATE( 
            [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember,
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
    MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentMonth] AS
        AGGREGATE( 
            [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.parent,
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
SELECT
    NON EMPTY 
    { [Measures].[CurrentDay],
        [Measures].[CurrentMonth] } 
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
    { EXISTING [Date].[Calendar].[Date] }
    ON ROWS
From [Adventure Works]
```

---

**EDIT**

To run nsousa's solution in SSMS I need to nest the `IIF` like this:

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentDay] AS
        AGGREGATE( 
            [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember,
            [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
    MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentMonth] AS
        IIF(
            ISEMPTY([Measures].[CurrentDay]),
            NULL,
            AGGREGATE( 
                [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.parent,
                [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount]
                )
        )
SELECT
    NON EMPTY 
    { [Measures].[CurrentDay],
        [Measures].[CurrentMonth] } 
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
    { [Date].[Calendar].[Date] }
    ON ROWS
From [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine your measure:

```
WITH
    MEMBER [Measure].[Not Null Reseller Sales Amount] AS
        IIF( IsEmpty( [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] ), 0, [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount] )
    MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentDay] AS
        AGGREGATE( 
            [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember,
            [Measures].[Not Null Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
    MEMBER [Measures].[CurrentMonth] AS
        AGGREGATE( 
            [Date].[Calendar].Currentmember.parent,
            [Measures].[Not Null Reseller Sales Amount]
        )
SELECT
    NON EMPTY 
    { [Measures].[CurrentDay],
        [Measures].[CurrentMonth] } 
    ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY 
    { [Date].[Calendar].[Date] }
    ON ROWS
From [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: +1 thanks. This errors on my machine saying "Aggregate functions cannot be used on calculated members in the Measures dimension" which seems to make sense looking at the logic of your solution. `ISEMPTY` is definitely the right way forward - I'd suggest getting rid of `[Measure].[Not Null Reseller Sales Amount]` and then just nesting a `IIF( IsEmpty(...` around the `AGGREGATE` of CurrentMonth...

Comment: Whether you should add another calculated member or not, it's more a matter of personal taste. I'd rather have lots of calculated members and have a simpler select statement. In Mondrian (Pentaho's MDX implementation) I have no problem aggregating using calculated members, it could be a limitation of your implementation.

Comment: The SELECT is the same - I'll add variant to the OP. I'm using SQL-Server's management studio and will add this tag